# Can't delete old objects after adding new one in django

Tags: python, django

```
old_objs = MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user,...)# I must have to keep this line here. Because the new object is related to old objects
old_objs.delete()
```

I've a Model named **MyModel**. I filtered some old objects and keep them in a variable,

then add a new object.

Now if I want to delete `old_objs`, it delete all the objects including new object.

I want to keep the new object and delete old objects.

Comment: It's very hard to say witout Model definition but I guess you should check on_delete https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing that behavior since `old_objs` is a queryset, and `.delete()` does `DELETE FROM ... WHERE user = ...` without loading all the objects.

You could do e.g.

```
old_objs = MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
new_instance = MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user,...)
old_objs.exclude(pk=new_instance.pk).delete()
```

to exclude the freshly created object but that will have unexpected consequences when there are concurrent updates.

You might have a better time using transactions, so if the creation fails, the deletions are rolled back and thus will not have happened.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete() 
    MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer notes, `old_objs` is a queryset and is not evaluated when you create it, rather when you use it.

An alternative answer is to force an evaluation:

eg.

```
len(old_objs)
```

or

```
for obj in old_objs:
    pass
```

Do this before you create the new instance and you should get the behaviour you want.

If you're doing a load of other stuff and adding filters etc., don't do this as you'll hit the DB multiple times. Not great. If your code is literally as in the question though, adding the `len` evaluation directly after creating the qs should do the trick.